# Scrolling on listview creates duplicate meta data items

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am populating the list view with data I am getting from a JSON Array.The meta data that I am getting is being duplicated when I scroll on the list view.

```
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View tv;
        TextView t;


        if (convertView == null)
            tv = m_inflater.inflate (R.layout.item, parent, false);
          else
            tv = convertView;

        try {
            t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.text);
            JSONObject obj = _results.getJSONObject(pos);

            t.setText (obj.getString("title").replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""));

            t = (TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.created_at);

            JSONObject meta = obj.getJSONObject("meta");

            t.setText (t.getText() + "\n"+ "When:" + "\t"+meta.getString("startDate")+"\n"+"Location:" +"\t" +meta.getString("location")+"\n" +"More Info:"+"\t" +meta.getString("eventURL")+"\n");




        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("alatta", e.getMessage());
        }
        return tv;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
t.setText (t.getText() + "\n"+ "When:" + "\t"+meta.getString( ...
```

try this:

```
t.setText("When:" + "\t"+meta.getString( ...)
```

This is because list view reuses list item objects (`View convertView`), so on scrolling you get an already used `tv` and its views are already populated with some values.

Comment: I am also getting a url "eventURL" which is one of the the item I show in the row of listview.Different rows of listview will have different url's, I want to open that url in a webview.I have created a webview and have a new activity for it,I am having issue with implementing the onClickListener.

Comment: @Noble6: please ask that as a new SO question posting your current code on that.